# InfoPath 2013, repeating table (secondary source) values into 1 textbox?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath-data-connections

Using SharePoint Online and InfoPath 2013, how do I populate a text box with values from a secondary source. I found these [post1](https://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2013/01/infopath-20102013-concat-repeating-table-fields-into-one-field-with-delimiter/) and [post2](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/7124/36667.aspx) as references but still cant figure it out

I can display the filtered values in a repeating table using rules but how do I get the values onto a single text box? There are 3 values returned after applying the filter:

- NewsCoordinatorA
- NewsCoordinatorB
- NewsCoordinatorC

`xdMath:Eval(xdMath:Eval(xdXDocument:GetDOM("Directory")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Name/pc:Person/pc:AccountId[contains(../../../d:OtherRoles/Value, "News Coordinator")], 'concat(xdXDocument:GetDOM("Directory")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Name/pc:Person/pc:AccountId[contains(../../../d:OtherRoles/Value, "News Coordinator")], ";")'), "..")`

As long as I filter the first field in the eval expression, I get the right count (i.e. 3), but no matter what I do with the expression (either filtered or not filtered), it returns the same value.

If filtered, it returns:
NewsCoordinatorA, NewsCoordinatorA, NewsCoordinatorA

If unfiltered, it returns: EmployeeA, EmployeeA, EmployeeA -- it returns the value of the first item on the Directory List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it.  The first string in `concat` should be the text box not the field I'm trying to string together.

Formula that works:

`xdMath:Eval(xdMath:Eval(xdXDocument:GetDOM("Directory")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Name/pc:Person/pc:AccountId[contains(../../../d:OtherRoles/Value, "News Coordinator")], 'concat(., ";")'), "..")`